# List of all Salesforce Implementation guides

Tags: documentation

Is there a directory / list of all Salesforce implementation guides? I find the content in those guides go deeper than trailhead, and I prefer those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you visit the top level **[Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs)**, its "Browse Documentation" section has what looks to be a complete list.

- **[A Guide to Sharing Architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dat.meta/dat/dat_intro.htm)**
- **[AJAX Toolkit Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm)**
- **[Actions Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_intro.htm)**
- **[Analytics Bindings Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6indings.meta/bi_dev_guide_bindings/bi_dbjson_bindings.htm)**
- **[Analytics Dashboard Component Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6ent.meta/bi_dev_guide_db_component/bi_dbcomp_overview.htm)**
- **[Analytics Dashboard JSON Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_intro.htm)**
- **[Analytics Extended Metadata (XMD) Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_xmd.meta/bi_dev_guide_xmd/bi_xmd_intro.htm)**
- **[Analytics External Data API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_overview.htm)**
- **[Analytics External Data Format Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6dev_guide_ext_data_format/bi_ext_data_schema_overview.htm)**
- **[Analytics SAQL Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_intro.htm)**
- **[Analytics SDK Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sdk.meta/bi_dev_guide_sdk/bi_sdk_overview.htm)**
- **[Analytics Templates Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6e_wave_templates/bi_templatesdev_intro_wave_templates.htm)**
- **[Ant Migration Tool Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm)**
- **[Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm)**
- **[Apex Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ref_guide.htm)**
- **[Apex SDK for Slack (Pilot)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/salesforce-slack-sdk/overview)**
- **[Application Installation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.appExchang%E2%80%A6ta/appExchangeInstallGuide/appexchange_install_whatis.htm)**
- **[B2B Commerce and B2B2C Commerce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b_b2c_comm_dev.meta/b2b_b2c_comm_dev/b2b_b2c_comm_dev_guide.htm)**
- **[B2B Commerce for Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b_commer%E2%80%A6de.meta/b2b_commerce_dev_guide/b2b_commerce_dev_guide.htm)**
- **[B2C Commerce API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/commerce-api/overview)**
- **[B2C Commerce Einstein API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/einstein-api/overview)**
- **[B2C Commerce PWA Kit and Managed Runtime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/pwa-kit-managed-runtime/overview)**
- **[B2C Commerce Solutions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/commerce-solutions/overview)**
- **[B2C Commerce Storefront Reference Architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/sfra/overview)**
- **[Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6ce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm)**
- **[Big Objects Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object.htm)**
- **[Bulk API 2.0 and Bulk API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm)**
- **[CMS Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cms_dev.meta/cms_dev/cms_developer_guide.htm)**
- **[CRM Analytics REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_rest_overview.htm)**
- **[Campaign Management Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6rce_campaign_implementation_guide/campaign_management.htm)**
- **[Canvas Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm)**
- **[Change Data Capture Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm)**
- **[Chat REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent%E2%80%A6ve_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_understanding_resources.htm)**
- **[Chatter Answers JavaScript API Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.jsapi_chat%E2%80%A6meta/jsapi_chatteranswers/chatteranswers_js_api_intro.htm)**
- **[Connect REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_what_is_chatter_connect.htm)**
- **[Consumer Goods Cloud Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.retail_api.meta/retail_api/sforce_api_objects_retail_overview.htm)**
- **[Consumer Goods Cloud Integration Service APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/industries/rcgps-integration-service/overview)**
- **[Custom Address Fields (beta) Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.caf_dev_guide.meta/caf_dev_guide/caf_dev_guide.htm)**
- **[Customer 360 Data Manager Data Jobs API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.djapi.meta/djapi/dj_api_quick_start.htm)**
- **[Customer 360 Data Manager Global Profile Lookup API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.gplapi.meta/gplapi/gpl_api_quick_start.htm)**
- **[Customer Data Platform Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.c360a_api.meta/c360a_api/c360a_api_intro_cdpapis.htm)**
- **[Data Federation API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dfapi.meta/dfapi/df_api_quick_start.htm)**
- **[Data Loader Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm)**
- **[Data.com API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/sales/datadotcom-api/overview)**
- **[Data.com API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.datadotcom%E2%80%A6tadotcom_api_dev_guide/datadotcom_api_dev_guide_intro.htm)**
- **[Design Without Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6actices.meta/salesforce_limits_practices/limits_intro.htm)**
- **[Designing Record Access for Enterprise Scale](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_preface.htm)**
- **[Development Lifecycle Guide (Retired)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/retire_dev_lifecycle.htm)**
- **[Einstein Bot API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/einstein-bot-api/overview)**
- **[Einstein Bots Developer Cookbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_overview.htm)**
- **[Einstein Discovery REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6t_sdd.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest_sdd/bi_rest_sdd_overview.htm)**
- **[Einstein Platform Services Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.einstein_p%E2%80%A6in_platform_services/einstein_platform_services_intro.htm)**
- **[Embedded Service SDK for Android Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.service_sd%E2%80%A6meta/service_sdk_android/servicesdk_android_dev_guide.htm)**
- **[Embedded Service SDK for iOS Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/servicesdk_ios_dev_guide.htm)**
- **[Embedded Service for Web Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_overview.htm)**
- **[Engagement Mobile SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/engagement-mobile-sdk/overview)**
- **[Examples of Advanced Formula Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulForm%E2%80%A6lds.meta/usefulFormulaFields/useful_advanced_formulas.htm)**
- **[Examples of Validation Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulVali%E2%80%A6lidationRules/fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm)**
- **[Examples of Workflow Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulWorkflowRules.meta/usefulWorkflowRules/workflow_examples.htm)**
- **[Experience Cloud Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_intro.htm)**
- **[Federated Search Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.federated_search.meta/federated_search/federated_search_intro.htm)**
- **[Field Audit Trail Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_hist%E2%80%A6ention.meta/field_history_retention/field_audit_trail.htm)**
- **[Field Service Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/fsl_dev_introduction.htm)**
- **[Financial Services Cloud Administrator Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_%E2%80%A6e.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin.htm)**
- **[Financial Services Cloud Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_%E2%80%A6vices_cloud_object_reference/fsc_api_access_and_usage.htm)**
- **[Financial Services Cloud Installation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_%E2%80%A6a/financial_services_cloud/fsc_admin_preinstall_tasks.htm)**
- **[Financial Services Cloud Quick Start](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_%E2%80%A6services_cloud_quick_start/fsc_admin_preinstall_tasks.htm)**
- **[Financial Services Cloud Upgrade Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_%E2%80%A6vices_cloud_upgrade_guide/fsc_admin_postupgrade_tasks.htm)**
- **[Force.com IDE Developer Guide (Retired)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm)**
- **[GraphQL API (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/graphql/overview)**
- **[Health Cloud Administration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/healthcare_admin.htm)**
- **[High Velocity Sales](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/sales/sales-engagement/overview)**
- **[ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_intro.htm)**
- **[Industries Common Resources Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.industries%E2%80%A6/industries_reference/salesforce_industries_dev_guide.htm)**
- **[Integration Patterns and Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integratio%E2%80%A6ation_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm)**
- **[LWR Sites for Experience Cloud](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/intro.htm)**
- **[Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm)**
- **[Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/)**
- **[Lightning Flow for Service Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6sforce_guided_engagement/salesforce_guided_engagement.htm)**
- **[Lightning Platform Fundamentals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/document_retired.htm)**
- **[Lightning Platform Glossary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6y.meta/salesforce_platform_glossary/glossary_platform.htm)**
- **[Lightning Web Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lwc.meta/lwc/lwc_intro.htm)**
- **[Lightning Web Components in CRM Analytics Dashboards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6_db.meta/bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db/bi_lwc_in_db_overview.htm)**
- **[Lightning Web Runtime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/overview)**
- **[Loyalty Management Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/loyalty_api_overview.htm)**
- **[Manage Licenses](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_intro.htm)**
- **[Manufacturing Cloud Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mfg_api_devguide.meta/mfg_api_devguide/mfg_api_overview.htm)**
- **[Marketing Cloud APIs and SDKs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/overview)**
- **[Marketing Cloud Einstein](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud-einstein/overview)**
- **[Messaging Object Model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.messaging_%E2%80%A6_guide.meta/messaging_developer_guide/messaging_intro.htm)**
- **[Messaging for In-App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-in-app/overview)**
- **[Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm)**
- **[Mobile SDK Development Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/preface_intro.htm)**
- **[Pardot API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/overview)**
- **[Place Order REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_placeo%E2%80%A6.meta/api_placeorder/sforce_placeorder_rest_api_intro.htm)**
- **[Platform Encryption REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_e%E2%80%A6latform_encryption_rest_api_guide/api_rest_encryption.htm)**
- **[Platform Events Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm)**
- **[Pub/Sub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/pub-sub-api/overview)**
- **[Public Sector Solutions Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.psc_api.meta/psc_api/api_psc_overview.htm)**
- **[Publisher and Quick Action Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_intro.htm)**
- **[REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm)**
- **[Rebate Management Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.rebates_ap%E2%80%A6vguide.meta/rebates_api_devguide/rebates_api_overview.htm)**
- **[Record-Level Access: Under the Hood](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6a/salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood/uth_preface.htm)**
- **[Restriction Rules Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.restrictio%E2%80%A6_rules.meta/restriction_rules/restriction_rules_intro.htm)**
- **[SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm)**
- **[SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm)**
- **[SQL for Analytics Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sql.meta/bi_dev_guide_sql/bi_sql_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Analytics Plugin CLI Command Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6ence.meta/bi_dev_guide_cli_reference/bi_cli_reference.htm)**
- **[Salesforce B2B2C Commerce Plug-In CLI Command Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b2c_cli_%E2%80%A6eference.meta/b2b2c_cli_reference/1cb2c_cli_reference.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Billing Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.blng_dev.meta/blng_dev/blng_dev_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce CLI Command Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_top.htm)**
- **[Salesforce CLI Plug-In Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins.htm)**
- **[Salesforce CLI Setup Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce CPQ Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_developer_guide_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce CPQ Plugins](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_plugins.meta/cpq_plugins/cpq_plugins_parent.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Console Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console.htm)**
- **[Salesforce DX Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Developer Limits and Allocations Quick Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_overview.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Extensions for VS Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode)**
- **[Salesforce External Identity Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalid%E2%80%A6rnalidentityImplGuide/xid_impl_guide_retired_redirect.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Field Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/overview)**
- **[Salesforce Health Cloud Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_clo%E2%80%A6eta/health_cloud_object_reference/object_ref_overview.htm)**
- **[Salesforce IoT REST API Getting Started Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_iot.meta/api_iot/intro_api_iot.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Knowledge Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Maps Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.maps_developer_guide.meta/maps_developer_guide/maps_overview.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Maps REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/sfmaps/overview)**
- **[Salesforce Marketplaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/marketplaces/overview)**
- **[Salesforce Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide_redirect.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Mobile Notifications Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_overview.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Order Management Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.order_mana%E2%80%A6per_guide_html/order_management_developer_guide_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analyt%E2%80%A6cs.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Scheduler Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6_scheduler_developer_guide/salesforce_scheduler_intro.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Security Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityIm%E2%80%A6uide.meta/securityImplGuide/salesforce_security_guide.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Sites Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6e_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_overview.htm)**
- **[Salesforce Subscription Management](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/revenue/subscription-management/overview)**
- **[Sample Approval Processes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6pproval_processes/approvals_useful_approval_processes.htm)**
- **[Sample CRM Dashboards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6sforce_dashboard_samples/salesforce_sample_dashboards.htm)**
- **[Scoping Rules Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.scoping_rules.meta/scoping_rules/scoping_rules_intro.htm)**
- **[Search Insights REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_gui%E2%80%A6rest_aa.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest_aa/bi_rest_aa_overview.htm)**
- **[Secure Coding Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_cod%E2%80%A6ide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_guidelines.htm)**
- **[Service Cloud Chat Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_dev_guide_intro.htm)**
- **[Service Cloud Voice Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.voice_developer_guide.meta/voice_developer_guide/voice_intro.htm)**
- **[Service Cloud Voice for Partner Telephony Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.voice_pt_d%E2%80%A6uide.meta/voice_pt_developer_guide/voice_pt_dev_guide.htm)**
- **[Set Up Omni-Channel Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_chann%E2%80%A6ta/omni_channel_dev/omnichannel_developer_guide_intro.htm)**
- **[Setting Up Your .NET Developer Environment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6heet/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_overview.htm)**
- **[Setting Up Your Java Developer Environment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6nt_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_overview.htm)**
- **[Social Studio API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_social%E2%80%A6l/1-introduction-to-the-social-studio-marketing-cloud.htm)**
- **[Streaming API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm)**
- **[Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm)**
- **[User Interface API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm)**
- **[Using Date and Date/Time in Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.formula_da%E2%80%A6ormula_date_time_tipsheet/formula_using_date_datetime.htm)**
- **[Using Templates to Build Communities (Deprecated)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/guide_retired.htm)**
- **[Using the Reports Tab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6orts_tab_tipsheet/reports_enhancedreportstab_tipsheet.htm)**
- **[Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm)**
- **[Visualforce Performance: Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce%E2%80%A6meta/salesforce_visualforce_best_practices/vfbp_intro.htm)**
- **[Work.com Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workdotcom_dev_guide.meta/workdotcom_dev_guide/wdc_cc_overview.htm)**
- **[Workforce Engagement Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workforce_%E2%80%A6gagement.meta/workforce_engagement/wem_cookbook_intro.htm)**

Comment: I just [created a chat for collaboration](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138374/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-list-of-all-salesforce-implmentations-guid).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you win the "most linktastic answer ever" award, lol.

Answer (score 4):

One last post to add transparency on how scraping the [source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs) was possible, as that was non-trivial to figure out. The following script can be plunked into the browser console to output the cards for that page as markdown. I would have preferred bullets with a bold link and separate line for the description. Unfortunately, splitting links and descriptions was necessary due to character restrictions, which took a bit of reformatting.

```
let grid, cards;
grid = document.querySelector('dx-section[title="Browse Documentation"] dw-docs-grid').shadowRoot.childNodes[0];
cards = grid.querySelector("dx-grid").childNodes;
const readCard = (card) => {
    const anchor = card.shadowRoot.childNodes[0];
    const title = anchor.querySelector("dx-card-title").shadowRoot.textContent;
    const description = anchor.text;
    const href = anchor.href;
    return ` - **[${title}](${href})** \n ${description}`
}
console.log(Array.from(cards).reduce((output, card) => output + "\n" + readCard(card), ""));
```

On each subsequent pagination, the following script can then be used.

```
grid = document.querySelector('dx-section[title="Browse Documentation"] dw-docs-grid').shadowRoot.childNodes[0];
cards = grid.querySelector("dx-grid").childNodes;
console.log(Array.from(cards).reduce((output, card) => output + "\n" + readCard(card), ""));
```

One little caveat was that Chrome scrunched my two trailing spaces into one, so I used Python to expand that back out.

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
output = root.clipboard_get()
print(output.replace("** \n", "**  \n"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Corresponding descriptions. I had to split this post in two due to character restrictions.

- **A Guide to Sharing Architecture**
  Develop a sharing model for secure and efficient data access. Learn about data accessibility components, sharing model use cases, real customer sharing solutions, and troubleshooting guidelines.
- **AJAX Toolkit Developer Guide**
  Execute any call in the API, and access any API object that you normally have access to by using the AJAX Toolkit — a JavaScript wrapper around the API.
- **Actions Developer Guide**
  Action API provides APEX, SOAP, and REST interfaces that let you add quick actions to Salesforce applications. Actions let users quickly create or update records, log calls, send emails, and more, in the context of a particular object. For example, you add an object-specific action on the Account object that creates contacts. If someone creates a contact with that action on the detail page for the Acme account, that new contact is automatically associated with Acme.
- **Analytics Bindings Developer Guide**
  Describes how to create bindings in CRM Analytics dashboards by modifying the JSON.
- **Analytics Dashboard Component Developer Guide**
  Describes how to use the CRM Analytics Dashboard Component wave:waveDashboard beyond embedding it in a Salesforce page to increase interactive functionality
- **Analytics Dashboard JSON Developer Guide**
  Describes the properties that can be included in the dashboard JSON. Modify the JSON properties to create advanced dashbards that aren’t possible using the CRM Analytics user interface.
- **Analytics Extended Metadata (XMD) Developer Guide**
  Describes how to use extended metadata (XMD) to customize the formatting of dataset fields and their values in CRM Analytics dashboards and lenses.
- **Analytics External Data API Developer Guide**
  Describes how to use the External Data API to upload CSV files to CRM Analytics and how to specify the structure of your data by defining metadata in JSON format.
- **Analytics External Data Format Developer Guide**
  Describes how to prepare your external data files (CSV) and metadata files (JSON) before uploading them into a CRM Analytics dataset.
- **Analytics SAQL Developer Guide**
  Describes how to use the Salesforce Analytics Query Language (SAQL) to retrieve and analyze CRM Analytics data.
- **Analytics SDK Developer Guide**
  Describes how to use CRM Analytics Lightning Web Components, CRM Analytics Assets and CRM Analytics Aura Component, CRM Analytics Aura Events, and CRM Analytics in Apex.
- **Analytics Templates Developer Guide**
  Create CRM Analytics Templates from source apps, and downstream apps from templates.
- **Ant Migration Tool Guide**
  Move metadata components between your Salesforce development and production orgs in an automated and repeatable way with the Ant Migration Tool. The Ant Migration Tool is a Java and Ant-based command-line utility.
- **Apex Developer Guide**
  Learn about Salesforce Apex, the strongly typed, object-oriented, multitenant-aware programming language. Use Apex code to run flow and transaction control statements on the Salesforce platform. Apex syntax looks like Java and acts like database stored procedures. Developers can add business logic to most system events, including button clicks, related record updates, and Visualforce pages.
- **Apex Reference Guide**
  The Apex Reference of built-in Apex classes, interfaces, enums and exceptions, grouped by namespace. This guide also includes DML statements that you can use to insert, update, merge, delete, and restore data in Salesforce.
- **Apex SDK for Slack (Pilot)**
  Develop Slack apps using Apex to simplify collaboration and communication across your Salesforce data and services.
- **Application Installation Guide**
  Describes how to install a package from the AppExchange and roll out the package to your users.
- **B2B Commerce and B2B2C Commerce Developer Guide**
  Design an integrated business-to-business and direct-to-consumer commerce solution that uses the power of Lightning Experience and Lightning Web Runtime.
- **B2B Commerce for Visualforce Developer Guide**
  Add fields to the managed package custom objects, override Apex API calls for retrieving and processing data, modify how the storefront renders, and more.
- **B2C Commerce API**
  Ensure omnichannel flexibility by using a headless API to build custom apps.
- **B2C Commerce Einstein API**
  Use machine learning to power 1:1 personalized shopping experiences across every customer touchpoint.
- **B2C Commerce PWA Kit and Managed Runtime**
  Create compelling storefronts that combine the power of React with the flexibility of the Salesforce B2C Commerce API.
- **B2C Commerce Solutions**
  Enhance your ecommerce business with solutions customized for your industry and targeted at specific technical challenges.
- **B2C Commerce Storefront Reference Architecture**
  Build state-of-the-art shopping experiences quicker and easier than ever before with a mobile-optimized UX and efficient, modern site architecture.
- **Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes**
  Improve the performance of applications with large data volumes, and Salesforce mechanisms that affect or support the performance of systems with large data volumes.
- **Big Objects Implementation Guide**
  Describes the benefits of big objects, and details of creating, populating, and querying them.
- **Bulk API 2.0 and Bulk API Developer Guide**
  Quickly load your org’s data into Salesforce, or query large data sets with Bulk API.
- **CMS Developer Guide**
  Salesforce CMS is a hybrid content management system, where you can curate and share content, manage multiple language versions of your content, and control who creates what. See how to integrate CMS with other systems.
- **CRM Analytics REST API Developer Guide**
  Describes how to send queries directly to CRM Analytics, access datasets that have been imported into CRM Analytics, and create and retrieve lenses and dashboards.
- **Campaign Management Implementation Guide**
  Describes the steps needed to set up and use campaign management.
- **Canvas Developer Guide**
  Learn how to integrate third-party applications into Salesforce using the Canvas framework.
- **Change Data Capture Developer Guide**
  Receive near-real-time changes of Salesforce records, and synchronize corresponding records in an external data store. Change Data Capture publishes change events, which represent changes to Salesforce records.
- **Chat REST API Developer Guide**
  Take Chat beyond your website: Extend chats to native mobile apps with the Chat REST API.
- **Chatter Answers JavaScript API Reference**
  The Chatter Answers JavaScript API helps you mediate communication to the Chatter Answers UI. Learn the standard events and methods that you can use to customize the behavior of Chatter Answers UI components.
- **Connect REST API Developer Guide**
  Integrate mobile apps, intranet sites, and third-party web applications with Salesforce using Connect REST API. Responses are localized, structured for presentation, and can be filtered to contain only what the app needs.
- **Consumer Goods Cloud Integration Service APIs**
  Consumer Goods Cloud Trade Promotion Management (TPM) provides a number of Integration APIs to help clients get CG Cloud TPM up and running in their embedded system landscape.
- **Custom Address Fields (beta) Developer Guide**
  Create and manage custom address fields. Access address data stored in these custom address fields with a structured compound data type and as individual address components.
- **Customer Data Platform Developer Guide**
  Explore Salesforce CDP developer documentation, APIs, and resources to perform your customer data platform tasks programmatically.
- **Data Loader Guide**
  Describes how to use Data Loader, which is a client application for the bulk import or export of data. Use it to insert, update, delete, or export Salesforce or Database.com records.
- **Data.com API**
  Data.com APIs work with Salesforce Data.com Prospector and Data.com Clean to provide accurate account and contact data from Data.com.
- **Data.com API Developer Guide**
  The Data.com APIs work with Salesforce Data.com Prospector and Data.com Clean to provide accurate account and contact data from Data.com.
- **Design Without Limits**
  Learn how to make your apps lean and limitless for a large customer base with these strategies for eight different app design scenarios.
- **Designing Record Access for Enterprise Scale**
  Optimize your organization's record access control performance. Topics provide guidance on group maintenance, roles and object relationships for complex or large-scale organizations.
- **Development Lifecycle Guide (Retired)**
- **Einstein Bot API**
  Use Einstein Bot API to create a full-featured Einstein bot and connect it to your channels.
- **Einstein Bots Developer Cookbook**
  This cookbook covers some of the most popular use cases and frequently asked questions when building a bot that works for you.
- **Einstein Discovery REST API Developer Guide**
  Describes how to create and access Einstein Discovery predictions, discovery models, and stories.
- **Einstein Platform Services Developer Guide**
  Use the Einstein Platform Services APIs to easily AI-enable your apps with image recognition and natural language processing. Using the Einstein Vision APIs, you can leverage pre-trained classifiers or train custom classifiers to solve a vast array of image recognition use cases. With the Einstein Language APIs, you can harness the power of natural language processing to analyze text and infer the sentiment or intent behind that text.
- **Embedded Service SDK for Android Developer Guide**
  Give customers access to Service Cloud features right from within your native Android app.
- **Embedded Service SDK for iOS Developer Guide**
  Give customers access to Service Cloud features right from within your native iOS app.
- **Embedded Service for Web Developer Guide**
  Improve the functionality of your Embedded Service deployment by customizing parameters in the Embedded Service code snippet, adding JavaScript, or using an Lightning Web or Aura Components
- **Engagement Mobile SDK**
  Get started documentation for Engagement Mobile SDK developers.
- **Examples of Advanced Formula Fields**
  Review examples of formula fields for various types of apps that you can use and modify for your own purposes.
- **Examples of Validation Rules**
  Review examples of validation rules for various types of apps that you can use and modify for your own purposes. Validation rules verify that the data a user enters in a record meets the standards you specify before the user can save the record.
- **Examples of Workflow Rules**
  Looking for ideas on how workflow rules can help streamline your business? Check out these examples.
- **Experience Cloud Developer Guide**
  Develop custom Aura components and theme layouts to meet your unique business needs and transform the look and feel of Experience Builder sites and Lightning Bolt Solutions.
- **Federated Search Developer Guide**
  Federated Search is a feature that lets you search for information stored in external data sources from within the Salesforce user interface. The Federated Search API connects a Salesforce federated search connector to the external search provider so that data from external repositories can be searched and returned within Salesforce. External search providers have partnered with Salesforce to provide a search service that conforms to our API.
- **Field Audit Trail Implementation Guide**
  Field Audit Trail lets you define a policy to retain archived field history data up to ten years, independent of field history tracking. This feature helps you comply with industry regulations related to audit capability and data retention.
- **Field Service Developer Guide**
  Build out your field service operation in Salesforce programmatically using Field Service objects in the SOAP, REST, Metadata, and Tooling APIs.
- **Force.com IDE Developer Guide (Retired)**
  The Force.com IDE Eclipse plugin is no longer available. Switch to using the Salesforce Extensions to Visual Studio Code.
- **GraphQL API (Beta)**
  Aggregate records, request explicit fields, introspect the schema, and more with the GraphQL API for Salesforce. GraphQL is an open-source data query and manipulation platform for APIs.
- **High Velocity Sales**
  Describes how to use the API to understand your sales cadences and their assigned targets.
- **ISVforce Guide**
  Plan, build, and sell AppExchange solutions and consulting services.
- **Industries Common Resources Developer Guide**
  This guide contains developer documentation for features that are available in two or more Industries clouds.
- **Integration Patterns and Practices**
  Discover strategies for integrating Lightning Platform with other applications through specific scenarios.
- **LWR Sites for Experience Cloud**
  Develop Experience Cloud sites that load quickly and scale well using the new Lightning Web Runtime (LWR) and the Lightning Web Components (LWC) programming model.
- **Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide**
  Create Aura components for Salesforce for Android, iOS, and mobile web and Lightning Experience with JavaScript and Apex. Components can be used in standalone apps, Visualforce, Lightning App Builder, and Experience Builder.
- **Lightning Components**
  Build and customize Salesforce user interfaces. Use base Lightning components provided by Salesforce, and compose your own components. Declare component state in HTML, write logic in JavaScript, and add style with CSS.
- **Lightning Flow for Service Developer Guide**
  Associate records to actions and guide your users through multi-step processes in your Lightning apps
- **Lightning Platform Fundamentals**
  Get acquainted with the native functionality of the Lightning Platform by creating a recruiting application. Design and create objects, customize the app's user interface, control access to data, collaborate with Chatter, automate processes, and report on your data.
- **Lightning Platform Glossary**
  Get acquainted with terms that are specific to Lightning Platform.
- **Lightning Web Components Developer Guide**
  Use Lightning Web Components to develop apps using a standards-driven JavaScript model.
- **Lightning Web Components in CRM Analytics Dashboards**
  Describes how to create and use custom Lightning Web Components in CRM Analytics Dashboards. Follow the step-by-step guide and use provided examples to get started on creating custom Lightning Web Component widgets that interact with the CRM Analytics widgets you know and love.
- **Lightning Web Runtime**
  Lightning Web Runtime (LWR) enables you to build digital experiences that meet the high scale, security, and performance demands of modern web applications.
- **Loyalty Management Developer Guide**
  Loyalty Management gives you the tools and developer resources you need to create and run a loyalty program in Salesforce.
- **Manage Licenses**
  Describes how to manage licenses for apps installed from the AppExchange.
- **Marketing Cloud APIs and SDKs**
  Get started documentation for Marketing Cloud developers.
- **Marketing Cloud Einstein**
  Get started documentation for Marketing Cloud Einstein developers.
- **Messaging Object Model**
  Guide for developers using the Service Cloud Messaging feature.
- **Messaging for In-App**
  Provide customers with a persistent messaging experience directly from your iOS and Android mobile apps.
- **Metadata API Developer Guide**
  Deploy customizations between Salesforce environments with Metadata API. Examples of customizations you can deploy include custom object definitions, page layouts, Apex code, and settings. Also, you can create, update, read, delete, and rename operations directly on metadata components.
- **Mobile SDK Development Guide**
  Build standalone native, React Native, and hybrid mobile apps that access Salesforce data with Salesforce Mobile SDK.
- **Pardot API**
  Extend your B2B marketing efforts.
- **Place Order REST API Developer Guide**
  Access your organization's order and contract data programmatically with the Salesforce Place Order REST API.
- **Platform Encryption REST API Developer Guide**
  The REST API for Salesforce Platform Encryption lets you generate and manage tenant secrets outside of Salesforce.
- **Platform Events Developer Guide**
  Use platform events to connect business processes in Salesforce and external apps through the exchange of real-time event data. Platform events are secure and scalable messages that contain data. Publishers publish event messages that subscribers receive in real time. To customize the data published, define platform event fields.
- **Pub/Sub API**
  A developer guide for Pub/Sub API published on developer.salesforce.com.
- **Publisher and Quick Action Developer Guide**
  Learn how you can use Lightning components, Visualforce, and Apex to customize your app’s experience, including the case feed.
- **REST API Developer Guide**
  Build versatile and lightweight solutions that integrate your Salesforce data using REST API. This simple RESTful interface is powerful, convenient, and great for writing mobile and web apps.
- **Record-Level Access: Under the Hood**
  See different levels of data access, as well as table-level ("under the hood") views of record-level access. Prepare yourself to give the right users the right access to the right records at the right time — and do so in the fastest time possible.
- **Restriction Rules Developer Guide**
  Restriction rules let you enhance security and protect your data by allowing specified users to have access only to designated records.
- **SOAP API Developer Guide**
  Build robust, server-side solutions that integrate your Salesforce data using SOAP API. Choose the Web Services Description Language (WSDL) that fits your need, whether it’s a strongly typed representation of your org’s data or a loosely typed representation that can be used to access data within any org.
- **SOQL and SOSL Reference**
  Query and search your org’s data for specific information with Salesforce Object Query Language and Salesforce Object Search Language.
- **SQL for Analytics Developer Guide**
  Describes how to use the CRM Analytics version of the SQL query language.
- **Salesforce Analytics Plugin CLI Command Reference**
  An alphabetized list of CLI commands that you use with Salesforce DX Analytics plugin to create and manage CRM Analytics assets on the Lightning Platform.
- **Salesforce B2B2C Commerce Plug-In CLI Command Reference**
  Use CLI commands to create and manage applications on the Lightning Platform.
- **Salesforce Billing Developer Guide**
  Want to get started developing with Salesforce Billing? Check out developer guides, plugins, and Lightning components.
- **Salesforce CLI Command Reference**
  An alphabetized list of CLI commands that you use with Salesforce DX to create and manage applications on the Lightning Platform.
- **Salesforce CLI Plug-In Developer Guide**
  Discover how to develop your own plug-ins for Salesforce CLI. Explore the Salesforce CLI architecture. Learn how to generate a plug-in using Salesforce Plug-In Generator, use Salesforce’s libraries to add functionality to your plug-in, and debug issues. Learn about our suggested style guidelines for naming and messages and our recommended best practices for plug-ins.
- **Salesforce CLI Setup Guide**
  Learn how to install the Salesforce CLI.
- **Salesforce CPQ Developer Guide**
  Start working with Salesforce CPQ API and plugins.
- **Salesforce CPQ Plugins**
  Want to start working with Salesforce CPQ plugins? Check out our definitions, use cases, and developer guides.
- **Salesforce Console Developer Guide**
  Learn how to extend, customize, and integrate the Salesforce console with a JavaScript API.
- **Salesforce DX Developer Guide**
  Learn how to use Salesforce DX to develop and manage apps on the Lightning Platform. Explore the entire development life cycle. Set up a project, create a scratch org and source files, synchronize code changes between your org and version control system, continuously test and integrate, and package your app for release.
- **Salesforce Developer Limits and Allocations Quick Reference**
  Find the most critical limits for developing Lightning Platform applications.
- **Salesforce Extensions for VS Code **
  Use Salesforce Extensions for Visual Studio Code to optimize building and debugging code on the Salesforce Platform. From the VS Studio code editor, work seamlessly with scratch orgs, sandboxes, and DE orgs, and code intelligently with Apex, Lightning components, and Visualforce.
- **Salesforce External Identity Implementation Guide**
  Salesforce Identity can be used manage external identities, those of your customers and partners. The product is called Identity for Customers and Partners. Its license is called External Identity.
- **Salesforce Field Reference Guide**
  Use this concise reference to quickly look up details of the standard fields for most of the major objects in Salesforce.
- **Salesforce Functions**
  Salesforce Functions lets you extend the Customer 360 Platform with custom elastically scalable business logic. Salesforce Functions is designed to boost developer productivity by reducing your infrastructure responsibilities and enabling you to build and integrate Functions-as-a-Service (FaaS) apps using the languages and tools of your choice.
- **Salesforce Knowledge Developer Guide**
  Build a robust knowledge base with SOAP API, REST API, Metadata API, SOQL, SOSL, and Apex.
- **Salesforce Maps Apex Developer Guide**
  Apex developer guide for technical admins and developers using Salesforce Maps.
- **Salesforce Maps REST API Developer Guide**
  Salesforce Maps APIs bring the power of location intelligence, optimization, and visualization into your business applications.
- **Salesforce Marketplaces**
  Sell products and services from third-party sellers, extend your catalog range, and fill gaps in your product assortment. Expand your reach by selling more and monetizing your audience with assortments and offerings that span categories. Easy to start and ready to scale!
- **Salesforce Mobile App Developer Guide**
  Discover both the declarative (point-and-click) and the programmatic (code-based) features of Salesforce. Learn how you can optimize existing features such as Visualforce pages and quick actions for the Salesforce mobile experience, as we walk you through the process of making an existing organization mobile-ready.
- **Salesforce Mobile Notifications Implementation Guide**
  Keep your mobile users informed of important news in your organization by implementing notifications. Notifications let enabled mobile devices receive alerts, tips, and encrypted data from Salesforce.
- **Salesforce Order Management Developer Guide**
  Customize Salesforce Order Management and integrate it with your storefront, inventory, and fulfillment systems.
- **Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API Developer Guide**
  The Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API gives programmatic access to integrate reporting into a wide variety of applications. You can get report metadata, run reports synchronously or asynchronously to get summary data with or without details, filter report results on the fly, get a list of asynchronous runs for a report and results of each asynchronous run, and get a list of recently viewed reports.
- **Salesforce Security Guide**
  Implement your own security policies to protect your Salesforce org. Increase trust by confirming user identity, controlling access to specific apps and data, sharing objects and field data securely, encrypting data, and auditing changes.
- **Salesforce Sites Implementation Guide**
  Describes how to use Salesforce Sites, which enables you to create public websites and applications that are directly integrated with your Salesforce organization.
- **Salesforce Subscription Management**
  Automate the back-end revenue work needed to sell, invoice, and recognize revenue from subscription products.
- **Sample Approval Processes**
  Review samples of common approval processes to help you get started creating your own.
- **Sample CRM Dashboards**
  This guide highlights some of the great features available in Salesforce dashboards and reports, and includes tips on getting the most out of your dashboard components.
- **Scoping Rules Developer Guide**
  Scoping rules let you control the default records that your users see based on criteria that you select.
- **Search Insights REST API Developer Guide**
  Describes how to find facts for datasets and interpert natural language queries.
- **Secure Coding Guide**
  Learn how to avoid the most common security issues that Salesforce has identified while auditing applications built on or integrated with the Lightning Platform.
- **Service Cloud Chat Developer Guide**
  Create customized chat windows, buttons, forms, and pages for your company's Chat configuration.
- **Service Cloud Voice Implementation Guide**
  Implementation guide for technical admins and developers using Service Cloud Voice.
- **Service Cloud Voice for Partner Telephony Developer Guide**
  Connect your telephony system with Service Cloud Voice.
- **Set Up Omni-Channel Developer Guide**
  Customize your Omni-Channel records and console integration with Omni-Channel API objects and console methods.
- **Setting Up Your .NET Developer Environment**
  Configure your local dev environment for integrating with Salesforce using .NET.
- **Setting Up Your Java Developer Environment**
  Configure your local dev environment for integrating with Salesforce using Java.
- **Social Studio API Developer's Guide**
  Use the Social Studio API to author interesting new applications for extracting valuable marking information from the social media landscape
- **Streaming API Developer Guide**
  Receive notifications in a secure and scalable way with API Streaming. To receive notifications of changes to Salesforce data that match a SOQL query, use PushTopic Streaming. To deliver events with a payload of your choosing, use Generic Streaming.
- **Tooling API**
  Integrate Salesforce with your other systems using Tooling API. Metadata types are exposed as sObjects, so you can access one component of a complex type. This field-level access speeds up operations on complex metadata types. You can also build custom development tools for Salesforce applications. REST and SOAP are both supported.
- **User Interface API Developer Guide**
  User Interface API enables you to create native mobile apps and custom web apps with your own branding and look and feel. A single REST request returns enough metadata, layout information, and data to display, edit, or create a record.
- **Using Date and Date/Time in Formulas**
  Learn how to use formulas to convert between date-related data types, how to work best with timezones, and how the TODAY(), NOW(), and DATE() functions work. We’ve included several useful examples to get you started.
- **Using the Reports Tab**
  The Reports tab makes it easier to find, organize, and manage both your reports and dashboards in one place.
- **Visualforce Developer Guide**
  Learn how to develop custom user interfaces and apps with Visualforce, a framework that allows developers to build and deploy custom functionality hosted natively on the Lightning Platform.
- **Visualforce Performance: Best Practices**
  Create Visualforce pages that perform well by following these best practices. Diagnose page performance issues by using these troubleshooting techniques.
- **Work.com Developer Guide**
  Build custom solutions for Work.com
- **Workforce Engagement Developer Guide**
  Guide for technical admins and developers using Workforce Engagement.